# C# Emit , how to write a if statement

Tags: c#, emit

first of all , i have a class

```
    internal class Parent
    {
        protected void Write(string message, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{caller} :: {message}");
        }
    }
```

and i want to dynamic create a class , the class has a property "Name", if the property value changed then call write method , looks like

```
    class Child : Parent
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
```

> ```
>                 if (_name != value)
>                 {
>                     Write("changedto: " + value);
>                     _name = value;
>                 }
> ```

```
            }
        }
    }
```

what i want to know is the highlight clause.
how to write it in emit.
please help.

---

i want some code below

```
     private static MethodBuilder BuildSetter(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, PropertyInfo property, FieldBuilder fieldBuilder, MethodAttributes attributes)
    {
        var setterBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"set_{property.Name}", attributes, null, new Type[] { property.PropertyType });
        var ilGenerator = setterBuilder.GetILGenerator();

        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);  //this
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);  // the first one in arguments list

            //code should be here

        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return setterBuilder;
    }
```

---

**Updated**

```
var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Public,typeof(PropertyChanged));


var t = typeof(PropertyChanged);

var m2 = t.GetMethod("ValueChanged");
```

you see , when i create the type , i use a Parent type , and in the parent type there is a method called "ValueChanged"

```
protected void ValueChanged(object value,[CallerMemberName] string property = null)
```

i want call it in set method.

---

**update 2**

```
private static MethodBuilder BuildSetter(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, PropertyInfo property, FieldBuilder fieldBuilder, MethodAttributes attributes)
{
    var propertyType = property.PropertyType;
    var setterBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"set_{property.Name}", attributes, null, new Type[] { propertyType });

    var setIl = setterBuilder.GetILGenerator();
    Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel(); // define label to jump in case condition is false
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // this
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder); // _name field
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // value

    var inequality = propertyType.GetMethod("Equals", new[] { propertyType});
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, inequality); // '!=' method
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, exitSet); // check for inequality


    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // load string literal
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // value
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, property.Name);

    var m = typeBuilder.BaseType.GetMethod("ValueChanged", new Type[] {typeof(object),typeof(string) });

    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, m);

    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // this
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // value
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder); // save the new value into _name
    setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet); // mark the label
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); // return

    return setterBuilder;
}
```

---

**update 3**
screen-snaps 
[image]

[image]

---

**update 4**

[image]
maybe , i have found the error reason , see [Reflection Emit and Type Inheritance: Calling Base Type Constructors](https://softwareproduction.eu/2014/07/21/reflection-emit-and-type-inheritance-calling-base-type-constructors/)

**update 5**

finally , i got the error reason . it was not what i guessed at update 4 , it was caused by calling parent't method "ValueChanged" . before we transfer the parameter to the method , we should **Box** it as Object if the original data type is **IsValueType** . see the reference below ,

[C# emit , type value compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686465/c-sharp-emit-type-value-compare/54687187#54687187)

Comment: Have you considered https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged ?

Comment: you mean INotifyPropertyChanged? yes . i do it myself .because , i don't need the PropertyChanged event . i use a direct call to parent method . and i want those code created dynamically.

Comment: Almost always, easiest is to write code that does this, compile it then hit it with ILDASM and see what the C# compiler emitted as IL to get the job done.

Comment: You can use a site like [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANALiAlgGxgExAagD4AEAMABLgIwDcAsAFAHEkB0ASgK4B2ciAtgKb0DCAe04AHFNwBOAZQkA3RAGNuAZ0pVqhDYUTsJrAIbJiAJkIAFPeO7t1mgN43Nm4eIFxu8t2mJRCAdXGIbgAUpEQ8Skp6AObcMIQA2nwGyBIAstycwBIAcno8ALp0RPLJEoQAvISszMjIAJQOjoT2VE1tdACcQQAkAES2JbUSAL6EICDN4ZExw711qu2Ew43Laq2auCZ8ABYoXhPmltbrGi2Lzogyem5FhAD6+jyqjY64AMy3uTwvdj9tMXBmsQAOz3R7cMhLP5NJTcODQxxnRbtRAAM0IQQeeW4hAAhJUrshmNwGidkYiEeS/AFgr15Ns9KwYmg4AIJr1CJhCITifNKeSsTwKtyDMSFlTHKsJVL2jKNMMgA=) to quickly get the IL.

Comment: @AndyJ Thanks . it really help.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , yes i did that , but , i can't understand the emit clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AlbertK answer shows you the right way, I'll add the complete code. Hope it will help.

I put everything in one method.. refactor it as you wish.

```
// define assembly and module
var propertyName = "Name";
var propertyType = typeof(string);
var ab = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            new AssemblyName("dynamicAssembly"), 
            AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("dynamicModule", "dynamicModule.dll");

// define type, field and property
var tb = mb.DefineType("dynamicType");
var fb = tb.DefineField("_name", propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);
var pb = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
var get = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
var set = tb.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, null, new[] { propertyType });

// write the IL for the get method
var getIl = get.GetILGenerator();
getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // this
getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fb); // _name field
getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// write the IL for the set method
var setIl = set.GetILGenerator();
Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel(); // define label to jump in case condition is false
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // this
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fb); // _name field
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // value
var inequality = propertyType.GetMethod("op_Inequality", new[] { propertyType, propertyType });
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, inequality); // '!=' method
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse_S, exitSet); // check for inequality
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "changedto:"); // load string literal
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // value
var concat = propertyType.GetMethod("Concat", new[] { propertyType, propertyType });
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, concat); // concat two strings (literal + value)
var writeline = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { propertyType });
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, writeline); // write
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // this
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // value
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fb); // save the new value into _name
setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet); // mark the label
setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); // return
pb.SetGetMethod(get);
pb.SetSetMethod(set);

tb.CreateType(); // complete the type
ab.Save("dynamicModule.dll"); // save the assembly to disk
```

And the result

```
internal class dynamicType
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._name != value)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("changedto:" + value);
                 this._name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dudi Keleti , there are two points , 1. "op_Inequality" can't be found . i changed it to "Equals" . 2. when calling , i want Parent.Write method , not "Console.WriteLine" . see my updates.

Comment: @GoldliZh 1. Did you copy\paste the same code? I can find `op_Inequality` or help you to find. Anyway, you can change as you did but **remember to change also the jump instruction**.

Comment: @GoldliZh To call `ValueChanged` or any method you want, you need to get the `Methodinfo` of the required method. So if you have the parent type, you just need to do something like `parentType.GetMethod("name", flags, parameters)` and call it with the correct instruction (`Call` or `Callvirt`)

Comment: @Dudi Keleti , 1. yes , i copy the code , and op_Inequality not found . my VS is 2017(15.9.6)  and .net is 4.7.2  2. yes ,i used the var m = typeBuilder.BaseType.GetMethod("ValueChanged", new Type[] {typeof(object),typeof(string) }); to get the method , and there no error . but when i create a object , set property "Name" , there is a error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" i don't know why.

Comment: @GoldliZh Your `ValueChanged` method is not `static` and not `public` so you need to find it like this: `type.GetMethod("ValueChanged", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)` or with paramters if you have overload.

Comment: @GoldliZh Can you show me please what you write to get `op_Inequality` method and what error you got? Because this line `typeof(string).GetMethod("op_Inequality", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) })` should work for you. Keep on mind that `op_Inequality` is a `public static` method in type `string` (same as `Equals` method). Anyway, as I wrote you can use `Equals` (actually `op_Inequality` calls `!string.Equals(a, b)`)

Comment: @DudiKeleti  about "ValueChanged"  yes, you are right.

Comment: @DudiKeleti  , i update two screen-snaps , you will see  it returns null.

Comment: @GoldliZh The result is null because the type is `int` not `string`... I don't know exactly what your full code do so I just put an example of what you posted (Name property of type string). Anyway, It's not that important. You simply need to match the IL to the code you want to generate (like you did with the base type issue ). If you stuck somewhere with IL you can always ask a new question.

Comment: @DudiKeleti thanks. i got an answer from https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Objects/Internal/EntityProxyFactory.cs  .

Answer (score 2):

You can use a label, then you can jump to it using `OpCodes.Beq` that checks equality of two variables on the stack. Try this:

```
...

var toEnd = ilGenerator.DefineLabel();
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Beq, toEnd);

ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Changed");
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, 
    typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) }));
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

ilGenerator.MarkLabel(toEnd);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

It should be equivalent to:

```
if (_name != value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Changed");
    _name = value;
}
```

**Note:** Before the emitting `OpCodes.Beq` you need to push onto stack two elements (`value` and `_name` field).

You can see more detailed code in Dudi Keleti's answer. He uses `op_Inequality` instead of `OpCodes.Beq` to jump to the target label.